# How to create item list in custom StackPanel for specific custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls, silverlight-5.0

I want to create a custom StackPanel derived from StackPanel. But to add the items, I want to create a special list (can use a List<> or ObservableCollection<>). It should be something like this,

```
<mc:MyStackPanel>
  <mc:MyStackPanel.Items>
    <mc:MyControl Content="A" />
    <mc:MyControl Content="B" />
    <mc:MyControl Content="C" />
  </mc:MyStackPanel.Items>
</mc:MyStackPanel>
```

Not like this (currently this one is working),

```
<mc:MyStackPanel>
   <mc:MyControl Content="A" />
   <mc:MyControl Content="B" />
   <mc:MyControl Content="C" />
</mc:MyStackPanel>
```

I try using the ObservableCollection and it works perfectly if I add the items. The intellisense were also showing only one MyControl that can be added.

Now, how to get the list from the collection and adds it to the StackPanel i.e. using stkPanel.Children.Add().

Should I use Panel instead or how to get the list and added to the Panel? Thanks in advance.

PS: I tried several options, but the list always null, including using ItemsControl. So probably I'm missing some points here. Again using ItemsControl doesn't fit my scenario because I only want one control type that can be added to the panel.

Comment: Do you need indexing, selection support?

Comment: I think indexing is part of the list there. I only wants to know the mechanic to get the list in XAML so it can be added to the StackPanel children items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the collection changed event of the `ObservableCollection` to keep the `Children` property in sync? I've also included the `ContentProperty` attribute so you don't have to add items explicitly to the collection in XAML, this could be removed if you wanted.

```
[ContentProperty("CustomItems")]
public class MyCustomStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    public MyCustomStackPanel()
    {
        CustomItems = new ObservableCollection<MyUserControl>();
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object element in e.NewItems)
            {
                Children.Add((UIElement) element);
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object element in e.OldItems)
            {
                Children.Remove((UIElement)element);
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyUserControl> _customItems;
    public ObservableCollection<MyUserControl> CustomItems
    {
        get { return _customItems; }
        set
        {
            if(_customItems == value)
                return;

            if (_customItems != null)
                _customItems.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;

            _customItems = value;

            if (_customItems != null)
                _customItems.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML then looks like this (with the local namespace pointing to the project that the custom controls are in)

```
<local:MyCustomStackPanel>
    <local:MyUserControl></local:MyUserControl>
</local:MyCustomStackPanel>
```

Comment: @Darklce: Yes it's working. Thanks. I can add the items like this now,

<local:MyCustomStackPanel>
  <local:MyCustomStackPanel.CustomItems>
    <local:MyUserControl />
  </local:MyCustomStackPanel.CustomItems>
</local:MyCustomStackPanel>

But is is common/best practice for this to add and remove the event OnCollectionChanged?

Comment: @Rizzo Do you mean adding/removing the events in the setter? If so then yes, you need to make sure there are no references to the event handler otherwise the garbage collector will not be able to collect the object and you will have a memory leak. We only actually do that if the reference has changed though (if _customItems == value) return;).

Comment: Ok. I get it. Thanks a lot.